# Determining trait bounds for a Rust function template ( usize or Vec<usize> )

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a function template which I want to have the following signature

`pub fn convert_to_one_hot<T>(category_id: T, num_classes: usize) -> Vec<bool> {...}`

Here `T` can be `usize` or `Vec<usize>`. How should I determine the trait bounds for `T` to
write such a function ?

In the following are instances of the function for the two cases :

1. **When `T` is `usize`**

```rust
    pub fn convert_to_one_hot(category_id: usize, num_classes: usize) -> Vec<bool> {
        let mut one_hot = Vec::<bool>::with_capacity(num_classes);
        for index in 0usize..num_classes{
            one_hot[index] = false;
        }
        one_hot[category_id] = true;
        one_hot
    }
```

2. **When `T` is `Vec<usize>`**

```rust
pub fn convert_to_one_hot(category_id: Vec<usize>, num_classes: usize) -> Vec<bool> {
    let mut one_hot = Vec::<bool>::with_capacity(num_classes);
    for index in 0usize..num_classes {
        one_hot[index] = false;
    }
    for category in category_id{
        one_hot[category] = true;
    }
    one_hot
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a helper trait and implement it for `usize` and `Vec<T>`:

```
pub trait ToOneHot {
    fn convert(self, num_clases: usize) -> Vec<bool>;
}

impl ToOneHot for usize {
    fn convert(self, num_classes: usize) -> Vec<bool> {
        let mut one_hot = vec![false; num_classes];
        one_hot[self] = true;
        one_hot
    }
}

impl ToOneHot for Vec<usize> {
    fn convert(self, num_classes: usize) -> Vec<bool> {
        let mut one_hot = vec![false; num_classes];
        for category in self {
            one_hot[category] = true;
        }
        one_hot
    }
}
```

With that trait in place, the implementation of `convert_to_one_hot` becomes trivial:

```
pub fn convert_to_one_hot<T: ToOneHot>(category_id: T, num_classes: usize) -> Vec<bool> {
    category_id.convert(num_classes)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5748557409ca44232d1fd1aa35a4e22a)

Note that your vector creation was incorrect. `Vec::with_capacity()` is just an optimization, it does pre-allocate the space, but still returns an empty vector, so assigning elements to it will panic because it's out of bounds. You need to either call `push()` to append elements to the vector or create a non-empty vector to begin with, as shown in the edited code.

Comment: Wonderful. I am new to Rust and did not know this. This sort of example is also not documented well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Riemann Well, it [is in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html). Maybe the problem is that such a "simple" usage can be hard to find by googling because online forums tend to be concerned with more complicated examples that involve trait objects, blanket implementations, specialization (still unstable), and similar advanced stuff.

Comment: @Riemann Also please note incorrect usage of `Vec::with_capacity`, fixed in the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make do without a custom trait here, without sacrificing much convenience. If you accept an `IntoIterator<Item = usize>`, then you can pass in anything that can be iterated to yield `usize` items. This include `Vec<usize>` and `Option<usize>`. The latter can be used to conveniently pass in a single `usize` value.

```
pub fn convert_to_one_hot<I>(category_id: I, num_classes: usize) -> Vec<bool> 
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = usize>,
{
    let mut result = vec![false; num_classes];
    for id in category_id {
        result[id] = true;
    }
    result
}
```

This function can be called for vectors like this

```
convert_to_one_hot(vec![1, 3, 5], 6)
```

and for single integer values like this

```
convert_to_one_hot(Some(3), 6)
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2ca37a962d0c32a959a865ad65366cd4))